# NodeJS memcache get Buffer output

Tags: node.js, memcached

I'm trying to load data from memcached (EDIT: using the nodejs memcached package) but I keep getting back something like :

```
{ available_ads: &lt;Buffer 5b 7b 22 69 64 22 3a 37 31 34 31 35 2c 22 74 69 74 6c
65 22 3a 22 44 6f 6c 6c 61 72 53 68 61 76 65 43 6c 75 62 2e 63 6f 6d 22 2c 22 73
75 62 74 69 74 6c ...&gt;, cas: '2' }
```

I don't know much about memcached so maybe it's because of an invalid character. Here's the output from telnet:

```
[{"id":71415,"title":"DollarShaveClub.com","subtitle":"","body":"Our Blades Are F***ing Great","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=71415&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/ZUG9qYTJMsI\/0.jpg","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":480,"image_height":360,"currency":"","gender":null,"max_age":null,"min_age":null,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":500,"height":311,"length":94,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":true,"platforms":["web","mobile"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]},{"id":70799,"title":"Watch Settlers Online video!","subtitle":"","body":"Watch the entire video.","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=70799&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/1sZKP0QnIIY\/0.jpg","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":480,"image_height":360,"currency":"","gender":null,"max_age":29,"min_age":21,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":520,"height":325,"length":50,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":true,"platforms":["web","mobile"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]},{"id":70797,"title":"Watch this Samsung Memory - Meet Loading Ball Larry video!","subtitle":"","body":"Please watch the entire video.","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=70797&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/V11\/images\/982727944edee812a1a8c874a9abf65a.png","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":125,"image_height":79,"currency":"","gender":null,"max_age":34,"min_age":18,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":500,"height":310,"length":103,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":true,"platforms":["web","mobile"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]},{"id":72006,"title":"Nike: No Cup is Safe","subtitle":"","body":"Please watch the entire video.","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=72006&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/1jRoHGq9EoY\/0.jpg","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":480,"image_height":360,"currency":"","gender":null,"max_age":null,"min_age":null,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":300,"height":250,"length":63,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":false,"platforms":["web"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]},{"id":72049,"title":"Behind the Cameras - by Rolex","subtitle":"","body":"Please watch the entire video.","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=72049&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/k9o1lAq4zTw\/0.jpg","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":480,"image_height":360,"currency":"","gender":null,"max_age":null,"min_age":null,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":520,"height":325,"length":39,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":false,"platforms":["web","mobile"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]},{"id":72055,"title":"Huggies - Meet the Squirmers!","subtitle":"","body":"Please watch the entire video.","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=72055&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/tZnzHq3_xaQ\/0.jpg","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":480,"image_height":360,"currency":"","gender":null,"max_age":null,"min_age":null,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":300,"height":250,"length":33,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":false,"platforms":["web","mobile"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]},{"id":70794,"title":"Open Days 2012","subtitle":"","body":"Please watch the entire video.","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=70794&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/t4TnaVXQCa4\/0.jpg","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":480,"image_height":360,"currency":"","gender":"f","max_age":null,"min_age":null,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":520,"height":325,"length":58,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":true,"platforms":["web","mobile"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]},{"id":70795,"title":"Samsung Memory - Loading Ball Larry","subtitle":"","body":"Please watch the entire video.","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=70795&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/a5S668LyM5c\/0.jpg","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":480,"image_height":360,"currency":"","gender":null,"max_age":100,"min_age":30,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":520,"height":325,"length":103,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":true,"platforms":["web","mobile"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]},{"id":71522,"title":"Huggies Snug & Dry","subtitle":"","body":"Watch the dads test out Huggies at the mall","click_url":"http:\/\/b.v11media.com\/click?k=eeacbb44ecf52873acd8cfbe63ffdbea&uid=111&ip_list=%5B%2298.143.242.51%22%2C%2210.122.186.15%22%5D&o=71522&src=json","image_url":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/Kthn6DkQVL4\/0.jpg","cpa":"1","engagement_type":1,"image_width":480,"image_height":360,"currency":"","gender":null,"max_age":null,"min_age":18,"is_vc_ok":true,"width":520,"height":325,"length":33,"is_autoplay":false,"is_responsive":true,"platforms":["web","mobile"],"supported_events":["play","complete"]}]
```

Can anyone tell me why the nodejs library would output a buffer tag?

EDIT: here's my code

```
var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached('localhost:11211');

memcached.gets('available_ads', function(err, data){
  if(err){ console.log(err); }
  console.log(data);
  res.json({'click_url' : data});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
data.toString();
```

and then you'll probably need to use JSON.parse:

```
JSON.parse(data.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is when you store/set you'll need to store as String.

Example:

```
mc.set('keyName', JSON.stringify(thisObj), {expires:0}, function(err, val){
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    } else {
    callback(null, thisObj);
    }
});
```

Then when you read it back, just read it as normal json.

Example:

```
mc.get('keyName', async function(err, data){
    callback(null, JSON.parse(data));
}
```